# Error when inputting Site Address and List Name in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, power-automate, flow, 2019

I'm trying to get my MS Form to be added to my SharePoint List as a new item using Power Automate. However, I am stumped on the step where I need to input my Site Address and List name.

I'm getting this error:

[image]

I am aware that this is a SharePoint 2019 subsite. I also have contacted our SharePoint team and they've granted me full access to this SharePoint subsite but I'm still having issues. I'm not sure if this also contributes to the issue but the site's URL format is:

```
https://share.xxxxxxx.xxx/teams/x/x/x/subsite
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to find your site in "Site Address" option or are you using "Custom value" option? Can you confirm whether you are using SP online or 2019? In question you mentioned 2019 but you added `sharepoint-online` as tag in your question.

Comment: **Note**: To work with Power Automate in SharePoint server 2019, you have to install on-premises [data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/gateway-reference) and connect to Power Automate cloud to implement the solutions.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Thanks for the correction in formatting. The site does not come up in the dropdown of the "Site Address" entering it as a custom value presents an error afterwards as well. I've confirmed that the site I'm working on is SharePoint Server 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using SharePoint server 2019, the SharePoint site will not be shown in the dropdown of the "Site Address" while using SharePoint online connection.

To work with Power Automate in SharePoint server 2019, you have to install on-premises data gateway and connect to Power Automate cloud to implement the solutions.

Check below documentation and links for more information:

1. [What is an on-premises data gateway?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/gateway-reference)
2. [Can Power Automate work with SharePoint 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/868845/can-power-automate-work-with-sharepoint-2019)
3. [How can I see Power App and Power Automate menu in SharePoint 2019 list ribbon menu like we use to see in SP online list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/425172/how-can-i-see-power-app-and-power-automate-menu-in)